# When using React Hooks, how could we set a state to some complicated data structure initially?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We may have

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

but what if we need to set the initial state to some complicated data structure, such as an array of 360 objects, each other representing the initial amount, the monthly contribution, the interest earned, and the final monthly balance, just like how we calculate the compound interest or mortgage.  How could we set this complicated data structure up?

How is using an IIFE:

```
const [data, setData] = useState( (function() {
  const obj;
  // set up the object

  return obj;
}()) );
```

?

I think one precaution is we don't want to run the loop every time the function component gets called.

Comment: Why do you want to create an array of fake objects? They won't pay you interest anyways...

Comment: to display it on the page, so that we don't have to create the spreadsheet and dragging 360 rows down

Comment: You want to display 360 fake entries while you are loading real ones? 'Please wait' or a loading spinner might be a better solution

Comment: no... no need to load.  The page can have a predefined 7% interest rate, initial investment amount of 5000 and monthly contribution of 1000 and the whole spreadsheet can be composed. It is "real" data. The user can alter any of the 7%, 5000 or 1000 on the input box. This doesn't involve fetching data remotely

Comment: If it is a constant with default values store it outside of the component as `const initialData={...}`, and then use in the component `useState(initialData)`?

Comment: If you want your initial state to not be an empty array. Create the initial variable `const complicatedObj = { test: "tis complicated ppl" }`, Whatever is its structure and pass it when you initialize the state. `const [state, setState] = useState(complicatedObj)`. You also receive the advantage of autocomplete in VSCode.

Comment: so my initial object is an array of 360 or 480 objects. the question is how to populate it

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way is to use a useEffect hook. I'll rapidly explain how it works:

```
useEffect(()=>{
//here you can do your computation
let myFirstField=...;
let mySecondField=...;

setData({
  one: myFirstField;
  two: mySecondField;
});
},[]) //putting these "empty array" after use effect ensure that use Effect is called only after "onMount" (at the beginning and not at every refresh)
```

I want you to notice a thing. Use state hooks aren't like normal state in components. You can't set only a field when you want to change it, but you need to reset the whole state.

Said this, use effect will initialize your state in the way you want. Inside this method you can also run axios request or whatever you want, just remember to handle what the UI is showing accordingly (for example if you perform an axios request, show a spinner for the user to understand that the page is loading)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) to initialize your data.

Comment: since there is lazy initial state, that means a state's initial value cannot be a function object if we want to... because if it is a function, it will get executed... ah, unless we give it and function and this function returns a function

Comment: Yeah, If you want to lazy initialize a function, just return a function in the function of `useState`.